# Join on same table in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have got a table `product` and the data is as shown below.

```
id     type     account_id    start_date    end_date
1      APPLE    100           2015-01-27    2015-02-25
2      MANGO    100           2015-01-25    2015-02-25
3      GRAPES   100           2015-02-25    2015-04-25
4      MANGO    100           2015-02-25    2015-04-25
5      APPLE    101           2015-03-25    2015-04-25
6      MANGO    101           2015-03-25    2015-04-25
```

What I want to achieve here is filter out all the records of type `MANGO` based on the `account_id` and add the other types associated with the same account based on `end_date`.

The result should look like as below.

```
id     type     account_id    start_date    end_date     other_types
2      MANGO    100           2015-01-25    2015-02-25   APPLE
4      MANGO    100           2015-02-25    2015-04-25   GRAPES
6      MANGO    101           2015-03-25    2015-04-25   APPLE
```

I have tried the below query on MySQL and it works but not able to get it working in SQL server. Any help would be great. The above result is all that I need to achieve in SQL server.

```
SELECT yt1.`id`, yt1.`type`, yt1.`account_id`, yt1.`start_date`, yt1.`end_date`, yt2.`type` AS other_types
FROM `product` yt1, `product` yt2
WHERE 
yt1.`account_id` = yt2.`account_id` AND
yt1.`type` = 'MANGO' AND
yt1.`end_date` = yt2.`end_date`
GROUP BY yt1.`id`
```

Comment: what should be the output if there are 2 other types associated with the same `account_id` for the same `end_date`? for example if you add a APPLE record for `100` and `2015-04-25`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the equivalent query in SQL Server:

```
SELECT yt1.id, yt1.type, yt1.account_id, yt1.start_date, yt1.end_date,
       yt2.type AS other_types
FROM product yt1 JOIN
     product yt2
     ON yt1.account_id = yt2.account_id AND
        yt1.end_date = yt2.end_date
WHERE yt1.type = 'MANGO' AND yt2.type <> 'MANGO';
```

Your MySQL query was not really working.  It was choosing an arbitrary value for the other types, which on your sample data just happened not to be "Mango".

Actually, this will work on both databases.

Comment: Be careful using DISTINCT as it can be very slow - if you want the rows unique use GROUP BY, it is (always?) better performance.

Comment: But GROUP BY requires aggregate_function in SQL server. I am not not sure how to define that.

Comment: `and yt2.type != 'MANGO'` should help filter out mango from other types. [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/258383/1)

Comment: The above query returns duplicate rows for me, one with other_type as `MANGO` and next as the expected other_type for each account in the result :(